# How to create a subset of a DataFrame by giving a condition regarding the column names

Tags: r, dataframe, functional-programming, data-analysis

Sorry if it is a very simple question, I'm new at programming. I want to create a subset of a DataFrame (eclipse dataset) by using specific column names. However, since there are 212 columns in total, and I need 41 of them, writing every single of the column names as a list would be too long (and not a nice way to code I suppose). So instead I decided to get the columns by specifying the beginning of the column names (which decreases the list to 15 elements). I have column names that start with specific letters such as "NOF", "NOM", "NSF", etc. and I want to extract the columns starting with these strings to create my new subset. I tried to run the code below:

`eclipse_train <- subset(eclipse, select = starts_with(predictors))`

Where the *predictors* is a list of words that I want the columns to start with. But of course, it gave the error:

> Error in starts_with(predictors) : is_string(match) is not TRUE

I could not come up with anything else to filter the columns that start with specific strings I wanted to create a subset. How can I implement such a thing?

Comment: `starts_with` is best used within the `tidyverse` and it expects(not  sure) a quoted string. Perhaps you can just use RegEx with some grep? Or maybe you want base startswith(not sure about case).

Comment: Try this: ```eclipse_train <- eclipse %>% select(starts_with(predictors))```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work either. starts_with function still gives the same error, asking for only string input and does not accept a list of strings.

Comment: Should be quoted(`""`) otherwise the `is_string` check fails.

Comment: @NelsonGon my list also contains only quoted strings, it just does not accept a list as values. And I know how I can combine grep using regExp with my function either. Because I am searching those specific letters not in the same list but in another data frame's column names.

Comment: ```predictors <- c("FOUT", "MLOC", "NBD", "PAR", "VG", "NOF", "NOM", "NSF", "NSM", "ACD", "NOI", "NOT", "TLOC", "NOCU", "class")``` is the list I created by the way.

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by including sample data with which to work. Use `dput(head(df,n))`. You cannot `map` a vector to `starts_with`. You need some kind of loop/`paste`ing with `grep` as done below or some `map`.

Comment: well since there are 212 columns, it is nasty to look at the result of the code you typed, but here is the dataset itself (I am working on 2.0 release csv): https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/softevo/bug-data/eclipse/promise-2_0a-packages-csv.zip

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `eclipse` data frame in the Note, use `grep` to find the indices of the names that start with the indicated strings and subscript by those indices. No packages are used.

```
eclipse[ grep("^(NOF|NOM|NSF)", names(eclipse)) ]
```

giving:

```
  NOFX NOMX NSFX
1    2    3    4
```

### Note

If the desired columns were contiguous, as in the example in the Note, then this would also work where we specify the first and last name.

```
subset(eclipse, select = NOFX:NSFX)
```

giving the same result.

### Note

```
nms <- c("A", paste0(c("NOF", "NOM", "NSF"), "X"), "B")
eclipse <- as.data.frame.list(setNames(seq_along(nms), nms))
```

which looks liek this:

```
> eclipse
  A NOFX NOMX NSFX B
1 1    2    3    4 5
```